# Groovy console won't load on Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, java, console, jdk, groovy

I've never worked with Groovy before.

I installed the executable and the latest JDK from the Java website.

I set my system ENV variables `JAVA_HOME` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77` and `GROOVY_HOME` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-2.4.6\bin`.

Console won't load, so I tried to restart my computer. No dice. I tried running GroovyConsole.exe directly from the groovy folder, as well as trying the GroovyConsole.bat file.

It won't work and all of the above are the only solutions I've found online.

Answer (score 0):

#### Groovy console won't load

> I set my system environment `JAVA_HOME` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77` and `GROOVY_HOME` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-2.4.6\bin`

Your `GROOVY_HOME` variable is incorrect. It should point to the root of your Groovy installation (which is one direct **up** from `bin`).

In your case the correct value is `GROOVY_HOME C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-2.4.6`

You might also want to consider adding `%GROOVY_HOME%\bin` to your system path.

---

#### Setting up your Groovy environment

> 1. Unzip the groovy archive to some logical place on your hard drive, I have mine in `C:\dev\groovy-2.0.5`
> 2. Set the `GROOVY_HOME` environment variables. On Windows, follow these steps:
>
>    - Optionally add a new System variable with the name `GROOVY_HOME` and the value of the directory groovy was installed in (mine is
>        `C:\dev\groovy-2.0.5`)
>    - Start a command prompt, and type "set" and hit return to see that your environment variables were set correctly.
> 3. Optionally add `%GROOVY_HOME%\bin` to your system path
> 4. Try opening `groovyConsole.bat` by double clicking on the icon in the bin directory of the Groovy distribution.
>
>    - If it doesn't work, open a command prompt, and change to the bin directory and run it from there to see what the error message is.
>    - If it is complaining about not finding parts of Groovy, then setting `GROOVY_HOME` may help

Source [Tutorial 1 - Getting started](http://groovy.jmiguel.eu/groovy.codehaus.org/Tutorial+1+-+Getting+started%3Fprint=1.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [Install Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/install.html)
- [Tutorial 1 - Getting started](http://groovy.jmiguel.eu/groovy.codehaus.org/Tutorial+1+-+Getting+started%3Fprint=1.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you set `JAVA_HOME` **before** you install Groovy and you use Windows installer then installer handles everything properly. If you've set `JAVA_HOME` after installing Groovy I would recommend a reinstall.